# Registration form with Country, Region, City - How to manage 2 million mySQL records?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a web application using the PHP framework CodeIgniter. The app relies on correct information regarding a user's country, region and city.

I currently have the registration form with a country drop down box(populated from database), a region drop down box (populated using ajax depending on country) and a city drop down box (jquery autocomplete using ajax depending on country and region).

My problem is the city database has over 2 million entries and is rather slow to auto complete. I have seen this type of thing done elsewhere eg. Facebook Events where the autocomplete for location is much faster.

My question is, is there any way I can speed this process up (optimise mySQL database, ajax calls) to make it quicker, or is there another way to do it using something like the Google Maps API?

Any opinions/comments/ideas appreciated.

Here are the basic definitions for my tables:

```
City:
countryid, char(2)
country, varchar(100)

Region:
countryid, char(2)
regionid, varchar(2)
regionName, varchar(50)

City:
cityid, int
countryid, char(2)
regionid, varchar(2)
asciName, varchar(100)
isoName, varchar(200)
population, int
long, float
lat, float
```

I used ISO standard lists to fill the country and region tables, and a freely available city database for the city table.

Comment: Are there any indices on the tables? Have you run your queries with `EXPLAIN`? Can you provide the queries?

Comment: Are you sure this is the most convenient way to approach this? Wouldn't it be an option to let the user enter their city, and show all matches after a few seconds of inactivity in the text field? I find region/city drop downs awfully cumbersome

Comment: There are 4360 cities in this world.  Not sure where you are getting 2 millions cities from.

Comment: @Yada: Really?  I somehow doubt that, since there are at least [18,443](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=509183) towns/cities in the US alone...  (Considering the semantic definition of "city" as the name of the place you live, not places with at least 100,000 inhabitants)...

Comment: @Gordon: Indicies are city : cityid, country : countryid, region : countryid, regionid. Should I make regionid and couyntryid indicies on the city table? I have not run the queries with EXPLAIN, have never used it.

Comment: Query example:

SELECT cityid, isoName WHERE countryid = '$countryid' AND regionid = '$regionid' LIKE '%$query%';

@Pekka: City is autocomplete, so no dropdown.

@Yada,ircmaxell: Sorry, I use the term city loosely. It is cities and towns. I live in Australia and I believe there were at least 10,000 entries for this country alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use www.geonames.org, which returns json for the data.

Sample usage:

```
http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?name_startsWith=San&country=US
```

returns:

```
{"totalResultsCount":12101,"geonames":[{"countryName":"United States","adminCode1":"AL","fclName":"city, ....
```

Pulling such data from your own database is not necessary.

Comment: after reading the doco this is exactly what i was looking for! goodbye 2 million record city table!

Answer (score 0):

How about for City table:

1. Try adding indices on `countryid`/`regionid` and `asciName`/`isoName` (whichever is used for autocomplete results)
2. Don't use `LIKE "%new york%"` for autocomplete query as in this form MySQL can't use VARCHAR index. You have to run it without percentage character in front of it: `"new york%"`.
3. You could hide city input field until user selects country/region - this way you can limit autocomplete query on `countryid`/`regionid` fields (and use their indices).
4. Time your autocomplete input to only send query after 1 second (or so) elapsed since last character has been entered.